# Gh-pages images not found

Tags: sass, jekyll, github-pages

This is my first time doing this, but I have looked at the solution on here and they aren't working for me. 
When I launch the page (https://xrehder.github.io/XJR-2016/) I get the following:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) https://xrehder.github.io/assets/img/logo-XJR.svg Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found)

I have checked my syntax and everything is typed correctly. I also plan on putting the page on a custom domain. I'm just trying to get everything working before I do that.

Comment: When I click on your link I can land on your page, should this not be working? I don't get that error. Otherwise, check this site abou SVG http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/28/awesome-github-tricks/

Comment: The site itself should be working, but the images themselves aren't loading and I'm not really sure why they aren't. Also thank you for the Link I think this will help in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out!! =D Basically I was using Jekyll to build the site on a local server but when I was pushing it to GitHub it was trying to run a bunch of stuff that it didn't need. I got rid of everything but the bare bones of the site pushed it and it works! www.xrehder.com

Thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the SVG file you are looking for https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xrehder/XJR-2016/master/assets/img/logo-XJR.svg

You can get these links by clicking "Raw" at a page like this: https://github.com/xrehder/XJR-2016/blob/master/assets/img/logo-XJR.svg

(I use these to illustrate the differences between `/blob/` and a `githubusercontent` link)

Comment: While I did use links, I used them to illustrate the differences between `/blob/` and a `githubusercontent` link. Even if the links were to become invalid, the links themselves would still illustrate the difference. @gp.